# how to add shadow to elements in android using api 29

Tags: android

It looks like there's a lot of information on how to add a shadow to an element like a toolbar or a footer, but none of them seem to work for me.  I'm working with api 29 (Android 10) and would like a current practice in adding shadows to elements.  Hopefully, today, this means not having to create a separate drawable and then setting that to the background and can be today elegantly achieved by setting elevation and without having to bring in another library.  Unfortunately, none of the simpler solutions seem to work for me at the moment.  Below is a simplified version of the most recent pattern I tried:

```xml
 <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#fff">
<Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:elevation="4dp"/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="lorem ipsum......"/>
<Button
android:margin="10dp"
android:text="Submit"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please list solutions you tried already, with outcomes.

Comment: try, this my solution